# How refactoring this function?

Tags: php, design-patterns, code-cleanup

I need refactoring this function with SOLID or clean code or design patterns, any can help me?
The switch I don't know if I can refactoring

I have created new functions for decoupling but switch loop it's driving me crazy

I added custom functions created by me, hasCorrectSugars check that number of sugars is 0,1 or 2
and checkSugars check that exists sugars...

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
    $this->setDrinkType($input);

    if (in_array($this->drinkType, $this->allowedDrinkTypes)) {
        /**
         * Tea       --> 0.4
         * Coffee    --> 0.5
         * Chocolate --> 0.6
         */
        $money = $input->getArgument('money');
        switch ($this->drinkType) {
            case 'tea':
                if ($money < 0.4) {
                    $output->writeln('The tea costs 0.4');
                    return 0;
                }
                break;
            case 'coffee':
                if ($money < 0.5) {
                    $output->writeln('The coffee costs 0.5');
                    return 0;
                }
                break;
            case 'chocolate':
                if ($money < 0.6) {
                    $output->writeln('The chocolate costs 0.6');
                    return 0;
                }
                break;
        }
        if ($this->hasCorrectSugars($input)) {
            $this->checkSugars($input, $output);
            return 0;
        }
        $output->writeln('The number of sugars should be between 0 and 2');
        return 0;
    }
    $output->writeln('The drink type should be tea, coffee or chocolate');
    return 0;
}

    protected function hasCorrectSugars($input): bool
{
    $sugars = $input->getArgument('sugars');

    if ($sugars >= $this->minSugars && $sugars <= $this->maxSugars) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

protected function checkSugars($input, $output): void
{
    $sugars = $input->getArgument('sugars');

    $output->write('You have ordered a ' . $this->drinkType);
    $this->isExtraHot($input, $output);
    $output->write(' with ' . $sugars . ' sugars');
    if ($sugars > 0) {
        $output->write(' (stick included)');
    }
    $output->writeln('');
}
```

Comment: Why did you remove your code?

Answer (score 1):

I had a go at refactoring. I'm confused about `$this->checkSugars`, how does it differ from `$this->hasCorrectSugars`?

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
    $this->setDrinkType($input);

    // Unwrap the if statement and return early instead
    if (!in_array($this->drinkType, $this->allowedDrinkTypes)) {
        $output->writeln('The drink type should be tea, coffee or chocolate');
        return 0;
    }

    // Have a map of the costs of each drink type
    // This could be member variable, i.e. $this->drinkCosts
    $drinkCosts = [
        'tea' => 0.4,
        'coffee' => 0.5,
        'chocolate' => 0.6
    ];

    $money = $input->getArgument('money');

    $drinkCost = $drinkCosts[$this->drinkType];
    if ($money < $drinkCost) {
        $output->writeln('The ' . $this->drinkType . ' costs ' . $drinkCost);
        return 0;
    }

    // Return early if sugars are not correct
    if (!$this->hasCorrectSugars($input)) {
        $output->writeln('The number of sugars should be between 0 and 2');
        return 0;
    }

    $this->checkSugars($input, $output);
    return 0; // Should this not return 1?
}
```

And refactor of `hasCorrectSugars`

```
protected function hasCorrectSugars($input): bool
{
    $sugars = $input->getArgument('sugars');
    return ($sugars >= $this->minSugars && $sugars <= $this->maxSugars)
}
```

Comment: @RafaelPastorGarcía the `checkSugars` function does not seem to check sugars, but rather prints out the user their order? `hasCorrectSugars` can be refactored, please see this answer again.